# Calculating how many products to load from server based upon view-size

Tags: ajax

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. In this, there are products in the database which I would like to load using a Ajax request. While doing so, I have to check for the view-size of the users device, and then compute how many products it can see in immediate view and with some fair amount of scrolling. For example : It is normal on a PC or a laptop to load 30/40 products, but on a mobile around 10-15 products also would suffice

I currently have the client side functionality to get the view-size of the screen. I would like to know how to calculate the optimal number of products to load from server depending upon screen-size. I am posting my ajax function incase it helps.

Ajax function : The 1 in listallproducts/1 is the page number

```
$(document).on('click','.product-image', function(event){
                $.ajax({
                 url: '../listallproducts/1',
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function(response){
                         var newElement = $.parseHTML(response);
                         $(newElement).find(".products").css("display", "none");
                         $(newElement).find(".products").addClass("loadedProduct");
                                $("#freewall").append($(newElement).find(".products"));
                                initializeFreewall();
                                $("#freewall").find('.products').fadeIn(500);
                 },
                                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                                        alert("Da ist etwas schiefgelaufen" + xhr.responseText );
                                }
         });
        });
```

Any pointers are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply calculate the amount of products in javascript too, right? Like:

```
var productsView = 20;
if(screenSize<SCREENSIZEHERE){
     productsView = 10;
}
```

Then just send the offset number of current shown products + the productsView with the AJAX request. (I advice to use an offset number instead of page number in case a screen size changes.) Along with 'url:', 'type:' and 'succes:' put in:

```
data: { productsView: productsView, offset: offset },
```

I hope this helps..